# How to make a notification blink with javascript / HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, notifications, alert

Okay so I've been looking around for this and I cannot find it. I am looking to make the white glow that streams across the top of the tab in Google Chrome. It notifies a message in Facebook or google+. It's similar to window's glowing taskbar icons, except it's in browser. I know about desktop notifications, but those are too intrusive. I am looking for a way to call that with javascript or jquery. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The glowing tabs are relatively new features in Chrome, and are not something you can call/run directly. The implementation varies across operating systems (for example, in Windows 7 there is no "glow" as you mention).

The effect happens when the title of the webpage is changed. You change the title with javascript:

```
document.title = "This is the new page title.";
```

See this post for further clarification: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome/33rVaX7pmRE/arl1bLL98XkJ